# Why Rendering Components Directly To The Body Of The HTML Not Advisable?

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJS, it is not allowed, or rather discouraged to render a react component directly to the body of the HTML.

For instance, this:

```
...
render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

Would log a warning about how it is not encouraged to render a component the way I did. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Component's children are often manipulated by third-party scripts and browser extensions and this may lead to reconciliation issues. As a result, the recommended pattern to follow is to render your main component in the container element created in the app.

Comment: Any example of why this is an issue? This answer is merely repeating the error message, but does not provide the reasy "why".